# Show value to Textarea with ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show  value in textarea from a selected dropdown input field. The code is working fine with **normal input field** but i need the field as textarea and if change the field to textarea the code stops working.

```
<textarea id="mytext" class="form-control" style="height: 300px" name="text"></textarea>
    
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.productid').select2();
    $(".productid").on('change', function(e){
        var productid = this.value;
        var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            url:"getsignature.php",
            method:"get",
            data:{id:productid},
            success:function(data){
                tr.find ($('#mytext').val(data["signature"]));
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Here #mytext is the id of my textarea.
i have text area with  tinymce.in it

```
<script>
```

tinymce.init({
selector: '#mytext'
});

Comment: What is the purpose of using `$('#mytext').val(...)` as an argument to `tr.find`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="mytext" class="form-control" style="height: 300px" name="text"></textarea>
    
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.productid').select2();
    $(".productid").on('change', function(e){
        var productid = this.value;
        var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            url:"getsignature.php",
            method:"get",
            data:{id:productid},
            success:function(data){
                tr.find ($('#mytext').html(data["signature"]));
            }
        })
    })
})
```

As you said your script is working fine on input field then now it should work fine on textarea as well.

**To get value on textarea need to use html() instead of val().**

Happy coding :)

Comment: Tested code ```<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#test").html("hello");
  });

});
</script>```

Comment: Thankyou i forgot to mention one thing ie, text area with editor.. i have text area with  tinymce.init      


<script>
       tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytext'
      });
 </script>

Comment: $(function() {
    $("#lang").change(function() {
        var s = $(this).val(); 
        alert(s);
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(s);
    });
});